# MAC 上で 100MB のメモリで動く python プログラムが 200MB 以上空いてる Linux 上でメモリエラーになる

Tags: python, linux, macos

ローカルの MAC 上でデバッグした python スクリプトを
AWS EC2 上で動かすと以下のような messages がでてメモリがあふれてしまいます

```
Mar  8 07:11:29 xxx kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 4405 (python) score 382 or sacrifice child
Mar  8 07:11:29 xxx kernel: Killed process 4405 (python) total-vm:1625200kB, anon-rss:372468kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Mar  8 07:11:29 xxx kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 4405 (python), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

そこで以下のようなメモリプロファイラをはさんでみたのですが

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    memory_out = memory_usage((main, (sys.argv,)))

    print('peak memory used: %.3f MB' % max(memory_out))
  except Exception as e:
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit(-1)
```

MAC 上での実行結果は

```
peak memory used: 117.137 MB
```

となりました

EC2で実行前の top をみると

```
top - 07:15:20 up 3 days, 29 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.33, 0.94, 0.55
Tasks: 119 total,   2 running,  75 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 49.1 us,  5.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 44.8 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.2 st
KiB Mem :   980016 total,   223448 free,   594760 used,   161808 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   251552 avail Mem
```

となっていて 223MB ほどあいています
何度実行してもメモリエラーが再現して
その間に他のプログラムが起動してメモリを使ったということもありません

どちらも同じ S3 上のデータを参照して
botocore の認証部分が MAC では credentials で
EC2 は インスタンスロールを使ってる違いはあるのですが扱うデータ量は全く同じです
OS のメモリマネージメントの違いでこれほど差が出るものなんでしょうか

EC2上ではプログラムが完走しないので途中どうなってるかもわからないのですが
原因の調べ方を教えていただけるとありがたいです

python はどちらも 3.7.5
使用するライブラリのバージョンも全く同じでOSとメモリは
EC2 が amzn2.x86_64 t3.micro 1GB
ローカルが Mac Catalina 16GB
です

---

```
> sysctl vm.panic_on_oom
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
```

でした

Comment: 「プロセスが使うメモリ量」や「OSの空きメモリ量」だけでなく、「OSの総メモリ量」も重要じゃないかと思います。 / 1GB に対して残り 200MB は、OS が使う分も考えるとかなり厳しいですよね？ mac も同じメモリサイズなのでしょうか？

Comment: AWS EC2 上で `sysctl vm.panic_on_oom` を実行した結果を追記してみて下さい。

Comment: 追記しました。
> OS が使う分
594760 used の中にすでにカーネルが使ってる部分は入っていると思っているのですが、システムコールとかでカーネルが追加で確保するメモリはmemory_profilerには含まれていないくてその領域が100MB以上使用している可能性があるということでしょうか…

Comment: この様な場合、Linux kernel parameter の `oom_score_adj` にマイナス値をセットするという方法があるのですが [How set the "oom_score_adj" when(before) run target program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409429)、disk swap を喰い潰すかもしれませんので、お勧めはできません。

Comment: peak memory used と pythonプロセス全体のメモリ使用量は一致しているのでしょうか？

Comment: >oom_score_adj にマイナス値をセット
本質的に必要ならメモリの多いインスタンスにあげればいいのですが純粋にどこで200MBが使われてるか疑問です。

Comment: >プロセス全体のメモリ使用量
調べる方法はありますか？ MACで top を１秒更新でみてる限り 90M+ ぐらいまでしかいってないです。EC2 上だと 160 ぐらいまでいったあたりで落ちました。

Comment: top コマンドの結果を見る限りスワップがまったく割り当てられていないようなので、ディスクに余裕があるならスワップファイル等を一時的にでも割り当ててプログラムが動くか様子を見るのも1つの方法だと思います。

Comment: (追記された内容は) プログラムの使用メモリ量を抑えるのが目的なのでしょうか？当初の話から変わってきていませんか？

Comment: >プログラムの使用メモリ量を抑えるのが目的なのでしょうか？  なぜ環境によって使用メモリに差が生まれるかが知りたいです。昨日はプログラム全体をはるわけにいかなかったので具体例を出せませんでしたが、調査する内に再現できたのでコードをはりましたが、話が変わってるように見えるのであれば追記内容は消しておきます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アクティビティモニタでみたMAC上のpython動作中の仮想メモリは４GB以上要求してました

> Killed process 4405 (python) total-vm:1625200kB

で Linux 上では 1.6GB 要求したあたりで落ちてるので
落ちるか落ちないかは指摘していただいた通り swap の有無ということみたいですね

そうなるとメモリプロファイラが
peak memory used: 117.137 MB
とだしてくるのが何のメモリなのかが不明なのと
小さなプログラムでメモリを何Gも要求してくるのがふに落ちないですが

とりあえず質問の答えとしては環境の差ではなかったということでしめます